# Trying to make a scroll to top button to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a bootstrap made theme for a project of mine, and I decided to take out the scroll to top button for another project, but whenever I put it in the other project it won't work.

```js
// Back to top button
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $(".back-to-top").fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $(".back-to-top").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
$(".back-to-top").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1500, "easeInOutExpo");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #99aa37;
  color: #fff;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  z-index: 11;
}

.back-to-top i {
  padding-top: 12px;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>


<a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Everything seems alright to me with the JS script. I just need a fresh pair of eyes on it, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: If you want to design for the future take a look at [`scroll-behavior`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#propdef-scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine, i assume you did not included easing library. You can use ease library to make special easing to use for animating, like this link: [Easing Functions](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294)

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $(".back-to-top").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
      $(".back-to-top").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });
  $(".back-to-top").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1500);
    return false;
  });
```

```css
.back-to-top{
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #99aa37;
  color: #fff;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  z-index: 11;
  }

.back-to-top i{
  padding-top: 12px;
  color: #fff
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>
<h1> HEllo </h1>


<a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Please read this article, especially ease section: [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: This did the trick, but the thing is, I already had: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: That line of code is just for StackOverflow. You just copy/paste the JS part

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<!-- in HTML file -->
<h1 id="top">your text</h1>
    <a href="#top"class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>



// in JS File
    $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          return false;
        });
```